# Adding asplabel to .net aspx page with text

Tags: asp.net, label

I want to add a label to .NET ASPX page. When I do `<asp:label />` nothing appears? I want it to say "Hello World"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the label to runat server, and then set its text.

```
<asp:label runat="server" Text="Hello World" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I should be:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Hello World" />
```